# Javascript: function binding does not work with caller

Tags: javascript, function, this, bind

I have a function `foo` that calls function `bar`. **`foo` is bound to an element `test`.**

When being called, `bar` stores its `caller` function (`foo`) inside the set `s`. When I now run the function `foo` inside `s`, strangely `this` is now set to **`Window`**. But I did bind the function, so what am I getting wrong?

```js
var s = new Set();

function bar() {
  s.add(bar.caller)
}

var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.foo = (function() {
  bar();
  console.log(this);
}).bind(test);

test.foo(); // output: test div
s.forEach(fn => fn()); // output: Window object
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future." ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) I can't tell you how it works cause it is implementation specific.

Comment: @JonasWilms Fair enough, but I would reckon it has nothing to do with `caller` as it seems to be poiting to the correct function. I thought it had something to do with how I then execute this function.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Thanks, but it doesn't

Comment: @DonFuchs I suggest you analyze this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/7080548, especially the *Examples* part - 3rd example is pretty similar to what your code does

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bound function basically calls the function it is binding over¹ with the bounded this, so the callstack of your code looks like

```
 [Bound] test.foo -> test.foo -> bar
```

So from bar's point of view, it was called from `test.foo` not from the bound function.²

---

¹ as stated in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects):

> A bound function is an exotic object that wraps another function object. A bound function is callable (it has a [[Call]] internal method and may have a [[Construct]] internal method). **Calling a bound function generally results in a call of its wrapped function**

---

² wether [`function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) returns the upmost callstack entry is not quite clear, as it is not specified. That's an assumption.

Comment: oddly enough logging ```bar.caller.toString()``` does give the source code of ```test.foo```, but inside of ```bar```, checking for strict equality (```bar.caller === test.foo```) returns ```false```. Setting ```test.foo.dummy=2``` gives ```undefined``` as well for ```console.log(bar.caller.dummy)```

Comment: @user753642 `bar.caller === test.foo` returning `false` actually does comply with JonasWilms answer, because `test.foo` is the bound `foo` whereas `bar.caller` the unbound one

Comment: @user753642 And as for setting `test.foo.dummy = 2` and reading it from `bar`, this is not working as you are again acting on the bound `foo`; if you set `foo.dummy` before binding, you can access `dummy` from `bar` too

Comment: @JonasWilms That makes sense to me, great answer

Comment: yes I overlooked the part : it was called from test.foo __not from the bound function__. I also checked ```foo.dummy``` which is indeed accessible from ```bar``` as "predicted"